# Illustrator CS4: Nodify artboard maintaining center point

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to modify an Illustrator artboard, while maintaining the center point. My normal workflow would be to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while dragging but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the numerical `width` and `height` of the edit artboard tool modifies the size maintaining the center point.